# How to trigger a binded action from a button?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift2, osx-elcapitan

I have a subclass of NSButton, but I don't want to binded action to be triggered when user will make mouse down/up on the button.

How can I trigger that from another function?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the function declaration to something like this:

```
@IBAction doSomething() {
    // ...
}
```

You can both connect it to your `NSButton` instance, as well as call it from your code with `doSomething()`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i don't want to do this. If i do this i will call this action from a single place. I want to trigger default action method. Look at this image: http://postimg.org/image/qkvfv38mz/ . This method i want to be triggered when i want..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: This is a subclass of NSButton. I don't want to add in subclass an IBAction. I want a way to trigger the connected action to my buttonS, another that calling super.mouseDown(...).

Comment: You have an `IBAction` in your screenshot. You can simply call it after you remove its argument, just like I suggested in my answer.